# How can I import angular in webpack?

Tags: webpack

When I try to import `angular.min.js` in my `app.js` file for webpack, it neither generates error nor works.
I tried to import in each ways separately but none of them works.

`import 'angular/angular.min.js';
 import 'angular';
 import angular from 'angular';`

any suggestion please!
thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean AngularJS (1.x) or modern Angular?

Comment: Yes Angular JS(1.x)

Comment: Then this should help: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/

Comment: I have seen and tried it before, but it doesn't work....anything better?Thank you very much.